# Proxy over redis, HAProxy or twemproxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, redis

The best way to hide switching of master/slave redis servers, is to use a proxy over master server.

Among proxy candidates, there is two more important (and used) choices: [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) and 
[haproxy(>=1.5)](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/01/02/haproxy-advanced-redis-health-check/)

If we are not interested of some twemproxy features (like sharding) (and intrested only on proxing job), which one is better (and why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need sharding, haproxy is a good choice.

haproxy is transparent, so you can use all redis command(scan/keys/info ...)

but you may need sharding someday :)